# NullReferenceException when changing skin/theme via Application.Current.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, nullreferenceexception

I am writing an wpf application with multiple skins. The code to switch theme is as below:

```
try
{
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( resource );
}
catch( Exception ex )
{

}
```

The first time the code is called (to switch to a new theme), it is executed successfully; however, any subsequent calls to the same code would throw System.NullReferenceException.

The way I set up my themes are similar to what described here: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/22/simple-skinnable-and-theme-management-in-wpf-user-interface/.

Has anyone seen this error before? How do I go about debugging this since the exception is thrown else where?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry.GetFlattenedEntry(RequestFlags requests)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, OperationType operationType)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyStyleOrTemplateValue(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject container, FrugalStructList`1& exclusionContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& newContainerDependents)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateStyleProperty()
       at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateStyleAndReferences(DependencyObject d, ResourcesChangeInfo info, Boolean containsTypeOfKey)
       at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnResourcesChanged(DependencyObject d, ResourcesChangeInfo info, Boolean raiseResourceChangedEvent)
       at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnResourcesChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, ResourcesChangeInfo info)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
       at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
       at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnResourcesChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, ResourcesChangeInfo info)
       at System.Windows.Application.InvalidateResourceReferenceOnWindowCollection(WindowCollection wc, ResourcesChangeInfo info)
       at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.NotifyOwners(ResourcesChangeInfo info)
       at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnMergedDictionariesChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
       at System.Windows.ResourceDictionaryCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, ResourceDictionary item)
       at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same link you described above, you must first clear MergedDictionaries and then add. as following.

```
try 
{ 
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( resource ); 
} 
catch( Exception ex ) 
{ 

}
```

The reason you are getting errors on subsequent calls because the dictionaries maintain only one key for one resource its like hashtable and multiple keys might be creating problem if you just keep on adding different themes with same keys defined in them.

Comment: Can you check that for first time, only one specific theme is giving error or all are giving error?? I can see two possibilities, 1) If animation or any Storyboard is running and if you try to change theme this error might come, 2) If Inherited property becomes null somehow, inherited properties are the ones like TextElement.Foreground etc. Try creating theme one by one, like first create smaller version with only colors changed, then see if everything is working or not, then try adding animations one by one.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was the application.current what gave null value, and that has no .resources (or .mainwindow what i actually wanted)